# concatenate two vectors for divide and conquer algorithm c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm trying to get a divide and conquer algorithm working that returns a vector, and since it's a divide and conquer algorithm it obviously needs to run more than one instance at a time. The problem is when it comes down to the return portion.

Right now I have:

```
vector<MyObject> MyProgram(...){
    ...Code that's not important...
    return MyProgram(...) + MyProgram(...);
}
```

unfortunately apparently I can't just use the + operand. I know that you can concatenate vectors by inserting one into the other, or copying one into the other, but then MyProgram would be getting called one after the other, not simultaneously.

Comment: `MyProgram` is a function, so it's always called one after the other anyway.

Comment: It would be getting called one after the other **either way** - the only way things happen simultaneously is if you multi-thread, which you need to specifically write code for.

Comment: For parallel programming you need to setup multiple threads doing the job done. It's a complex task. The effectiveness has to be evaluated for every specific situation. I doubt it will be in your case also because you have a recursive function.

Comment: @andreaplanet: It's not *that* complex, but it's also not as simple as OP apparently thinks. And recursion by itself is not a reason why it should be slow

Answer (score 1):

I'm literally *guessing* that this is what you're trying to accomplish, but it is conjecture at best, so let me know whether this answer should be deleted due to being inapplicable.

The following defines a function that returns an empty vector if the argument is zero. Otherwise is returns a vector of N instances of the value N concatenated with the function evaluated at N-1. The concatenation is done asynchronously via a separate thread, thereby giving you the *potential* for concurrency.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>

std::vector<unsigned int> MyFunction(unsigned arg)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> result;
    if (arg == 0)
        return result;

    auto fc = std::async(std::launch::async, MyFunction, arg-1);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<arg; ++i)
        result.emplace_back(arg);

    std::vector<unsigned int> theirs = fc.get();
    result.insert(result.begin(), theirs.begin(), theirs.end());
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> res = MyFunction(8);
    for (auto x : res)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Each miniature sequence is generated on a separate thread except the first one, in this case the sequence of 8's, generated on the primary thread.

Anyway, I hope it gives you some ideas.

Comment: I think the main goal is not to make the vector concatenation concurrent but the whole MyProgram function executed in parallel. BTW nice code.

Comment: @andreaplanet Thanks. As I said, I had a hard time even understanding what was really going on. The code above should execute correctly in parallel, but I often get the future-destructor logic backwards, so for all I know I just spewed a giant sequential waste of time =P. At least the formatting is pretty.

Comment: If I understand correctly your suggestion can be written also as return MyProgram(...)+MyProgram(...); replaced with something like return std::async(std::launch::async, MyProgram, ...).get() + std::async(std::launch::async, MyProgram, ...).get();

Comment: @andreaplanet You could. Gotta be careful with temporaries, and I generally error on the side of caution regarding that (in case it wasn't obvious. But there is no reason to launch two threads if the *launcher* is then going to do *nothing* but wait for *both* of them to finish. You're better off doing half the work on one thread, the other on the *current* thread, which is the purpose I was hopefully conveying above.

Comment: Yes, at the beginning I wanted to give a simpler answer about a multithreaded solution, then I too realized that recursion would create a lot of threads waiting for nothing and we cant create too many. A processing queue optimized for a recusrive function is needed and so I realized it will be more complicated than a simple parallel execution of independent stuff.

Comment: @andreaplanet exactly. Not the kind of thing you want to try and mergesort  a 16-million element sequence with, for example. For things such as that you'd stop spewing threads and just let the ones currently running chew through the data once a threshold is obtained (like say, 16K element partitions or some such). But you're right, ideally a thread pool size-topped at hardware-concurrency count and  fed by a queue is the cats whiskers for such things.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper. Now just add an overloaded `operator+` to that class.

Such a Wrapper *can* look like this:

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
       Wrapper(const vector<MyObject>& _vec) : vec(_vec) {}
       Wrapper operator+(Wrapper& rhs)
       {
           vector<MyObject> tmp(vec);
           tmp.insert(tmp.end(), rhs.vec.begin(), rhs.vec.end());
           return Wrapper(tmp);
       }

       operator const vector<MyObject>&(){return vec;}

private:
       vector<MyObject> vec;
};
```

Your function would then be like:

```
Wrapper MyProgram(...){
...Code that's not important...
return MyProgram(...) + MyProgram(...);
}
```

---

Please check the comments for important warnings about your current design.